# Show a preview of all or selected running windows

Tags: windows

I am looking for a program that can show a preview of all running windows. It should run on Microsoft Windows. Any license or price is fine. Ideally the program would allow the user to select which windows to preview.

Example of previews of windows using  [Alt-Tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab):

[image]

I don't want to use Alt-Tab because one has to keep holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and it  doesn't allows select which windows to preview.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried out [Seer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccseer/?source=typ_redirect) it is free available tool where you can get a macOS like preview experience. The best thisg is it is free of charge as well.

Answer (score 0):

The  [Task View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_View), introduced in Microsoft Windows 10, can be triggered through the task bar's button:

[image]

[image]

One doesn't have to keep holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd>

To enable it:

[image]

Using Task View has the following issues:

- [Some of the window previews displayed on Task View aren't getting updated: how can I solve this issue?](https://superuser.com/q/1456312/116475)
- Task View doesn't allow the user to select which windows to preview.